# Why can't I access certain servers even though they are up?

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I'm having weird connectivity problems somewhere between my home network and certain servers - at least that's how I understand the problem.

I can access most of the internet, like `google.com` and `deutsche-bank.de`. But some sites, like `duckduckgo.com` and `meine.deutsche-bank.de` won't work, despite my many attempts. I have also verified they have no ongoing outage, all the checkers say these sites are up. My browser says just duckduckgo.com took too long to respond.". I would wait if it's temporary but it's been going on like this for a few days...

This is what I have tried so far:

- I tried other devices on the same network, with Windows, Mac and iOS. They all have the same problem, so it's not a software problem on one machine.
- My DNS works properly and returns `40.114.177.156` for `duckduckgo.com`. Setting the DNS server manually and flushing the DNS cache doesn't change anything in the situation.
- I can successfully ping `google.com`, but not `duckduckgo.com` - I get no response.
- I tried temporarily disabling the firewall on my router I got from my ISP (Vodafone) - it didn't help.
- I also have an AP from Apple between my machines and the router. It works in pass-through mode but just in case I tried bypassing it with a cable connected directly to the router - it also doesn't help.
- The only thing I eventually got from `duckduckgo.com` was a redirect from http to https - but then, on https, I get no response for the initial request. From `meine.deutsche-bank.de`, I get no response at all.
- I checked that my external IP is not on any blacklist (at least according to the checker on ipvoid.com).

Here are some `tracert` attempts:

```
C:\Users\Miko>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [142.250.181.206]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  kabelbox.local [192.168.0.1]
  2    21 ms    20 ms    19 ms  ip53a9b789.static.kabel-deutschland.de [83.169.183.137]
  3    21 ms    21 ms    20 ms  ip5886ed8d.static.kabel-deutschland.de [88.134.237.141]
  4    29 ms    28 ms    35 ms  145.254.3.80
  5    29 ms    24 ms    26 ms  145.254.2.195
  6    29 ms    27 ms    28 ms  74.125.48.122
  7    28 ms    24 ms    25 ms  142.251.65.73
  8    25 ms    43 ms    22 ms  108.170.251.208
  9    26 ms    25 ms    24 ms  108.170.226.3
 10    35 ms    32 ms    34 ms  209.85.241.144
 11    39 ms    36 ms    36 ms  172.253.50.111
 12    38 ms    34 ms    40 ms  216.239.54.169
 13    36 ms    35 ms    35 ms  108.170.253.49
 14    39 ms    36 ms    40 ms  209.85.240.161
 15    38 ms    32 ms    33 ms  ham02s21-in-f14.1e100.net [142.250.181.206]

Trace complete.

C:\Users\Miko>tracert duckduckgo.com

Tracing route to duckduckgo.com [40.114.177.156]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  kabelbox.local [192.168.0.1]
  2    25 ms    21 ms    20 ms  ip53a9b789.static.kabel-deutschland.de [83.169.183.137]
  3    20 ms    18 ms    18 ms  ip5886ed91.static.kabel-deutschland.de [88.134.237.145]
  4    27 ms    24 ms    21 ms  145.254.3.54
  5    24 ms    23 ms    28 ms  145.254.2.207
  6    39 ms    75 ms    27 ms  vodafonegermany.fra-96cbe-1a.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.198.11]
  7    26 ms    24 ms    33 ms  ae22-0.icr01.fra23.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.230.16]
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9    35 ms    30 ms    31 ms  be-18-0.ibr02.pus03.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.17.225]
 10    31 ms    45 ms    31 ms  ae120-0.icr01.ams21.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.22.242]
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.

C:\Users\Miko>tracert meine.deutsche-bank.de

Tracing route to meine.deutsche-bank.de [129.35.230.2]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  kabelbox.local [192.168.0.1]
  2    23 ms    20 ms    21 ms  ip53a9b789.static.kabel-deutschland.de [83.169.183.137]
  3    20 ms    20 ms    20 ms  ip5886ed91.static.kabel-deutschland.de [88.134.237.145]
  4    24 ms    22 ms    25 ms  145.254.3.54
  5    26 ms    25 ms    24 ms  145.254.2.207
  6    24 ms    24 ms    22 ms  de-cix.fra.akamai.prolexic.com [80.81.193.70]
  7    26 ms    21 ms    21 ms  po110.bs-b.sech-fra.netarch.akamai.com [72.52.48.200]
  8    28 ms    25 ms    24 ms  a72-52-1-137.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com [72.52.1.137]
  9    27 ms    25 ms    37 ms  ae121.access-a.sech-fra.netarch.akamai.com [72.52.48.205]
 10    25 ms    25 ms    26 ms  a72-52-51-148.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com [72.52.51.148]
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

How do I even debug such a thing? How do I check if it's, say, my ISP blocking certain traffic?

Comment: Google sites working and most other sites failing is often evidence of a Path MTU Discovery black hole. Google is about the only company that always sets their MTU a little lower to avoid this. Try setting your interface MTU down to something like 1300 and see if that clears up the problem. If so, try higher values until you find the highest value that works. Then make sure you aren't blocking ICMP traffic on any of your routers.

Comment: How do you know that it's specifically _you_ who can't ping the server, and not just that the server is ignoring ping requests in general? Likewise for plain HTTP requests, etc.

Comment: @Spiff I *can* access most other sites - there are just a few that don't work. Then, my routers can't be blocking all ICMP because pinging `google.com` works. I would experiment with clamping the MTU but this is a cheap home router that doesn't have such advanced settings.
@user1686, it seems this is indeed the case with these servers, they ignore pings. However this still doesn't explain what's wrong with the https connections.
For now I figured out I can work around this by tunneling my traffic through a VPN, but I hope I won't need to do this all the time.

Comment: You don't have to mess with router MSS Clamping to test the PMTUD black hole hypothesis. Just go into your network settings on your Mac and set the MTU lower on whatever interface your Mac uses to connect to your home network.

Comment: @Spiff oh, thanks! You're right, it helped! I set it to 1300 and now I can connect to these servers directly! I still find it weird, but at least now I know exactly what the problem is. Thank you!

Comment: You mention you’re on Vodafone. Do you have Dual Stack Lite (DS-Lite) or full Dual Stack? (Or even just IPv4?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google sites working and most other sites failing is often evidence of a Path MTU Discovery (PMTUD) black hole. Google is about the only company that always sets their MTU a little lower to avoid this. On one Mac or PC where it's easy to do, try setting your interface MTU (on the interface that machine uses to connect to your home network) down to something like 1300 and see if that clears up the problem. If so, try higher values until you find the highest value that works. If that solves it, you have a PMTUD black hole; something between you and the Internet has an MTU below 1500 but isn't able to tell you that, often because some router is dropping the kind of ICMP messages that allow PMTUD to work. So check to make sure none of the routers you control are blocking ICMP.

If your home gateway router is from your ISP and you haven't messed with MTU or MSS Clamping settings on it, you may need to contact your ISP's tech support team and ask them to resolve their PMTUD black hole problem.